# A number which has same frequency of all integers present

Tags: javascript, reduce

I want to check if all the integers present in a number has the same frequency.
Sample Input :
1212
Sample Output :
True

I am able to get  the frequency using reduce function . But not able to compare the values.

```
    let countOccurrences = arr => arr.reduce((accm,x)=> (accm[x] = ++accm[x] || 1,accm),{});
var obj = (countOccurrences([2,3,4,2,3,4]))
for(var i in obj)
console.log(obj[i+1]);
if(obj[i]===obj[i+1]){
    console.log("true");
}else{
    console.log("false");
}
  //end-here
});
```

Comment: Please may you fix the syntax errors in the example?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the Array `every()` method to check that every value in your object is equal to the first one (after converting to an array of values).

```js
const countOccurrences = arr => arr.reduce((accm,x)=> (accm[x] = ++accm[x] || 1,accm),{});

const obj = countOccurrences([2,3,4,2,3,4]);

const same = Object.values(obj).every((el, _, arr) => el === arr[0]);

console.log(same);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set to remove dupicates

```
let countOccurrences = arr => arr.reduce((accm,x)=> (accm[x] = ++accm[x] || 1,accm),{});
var obj = (countOccurrences([2,3,4,2,3,4]));
const isSameFrequency = (new Set(Object.values(obj))).size == 1;
console.log(isSameFrequency);
```